# Stubbing Devise in rSpec and Rails3

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

How would you stub Devise in Rails 3 with rSpec. I have a `UsersController` and a `User` model. Both of which are associated with Devise at the moment, I'm writing controller specs and I really am having a hard time with my expectations as the Devise `sign_in` is really jamming up the works.

Any thing will help.

Comment: With devise, you can completely stub out the user model:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I found that it is now pretty easy to do this. There was a problem with rspec2 and devise, but is now solved. I guess you would need to update your gems. Then you can write

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DoStuffController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before (:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

[UPDATE] On the devise wiki there is now a detailed (and probably more up-to-date) [description](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)).

Comment: Just as a note to others who might come across this. If your using confirmation, make sure your factory defines :confirmed_at or you pass it in.

Comment: There's a detailed description of this on the devise wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Comment: @KevinBedell, the URL is almost right - it is missing the last ')'. Thus, the correct URL is [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

Comment: I fixed the url in the post as well.

Comment: It would be nice not to touch the database on controller tests though... is there any way to mock this behavior instead of actually creating activerecord objects?

Answer (score 9):

You can try mocking the underlying warden (https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki) object which devise relies upon, here is a link to some details on how you can accomplish this with RSpec: http://www.michaelharrison.ws/weblog/?p=349 (entry covers some other topics as well, the solution you want is towards the bottom of the page.)

Comment: Thanks so much! Just what I've been looking for.

Comment: The new answer below provides a better way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387485/stubbing-devise-in-rspec-and-rails3/3512813#3512813